# why does mypy complain '"Type[Logger]" has no attribute "manager"'

Tags: python, mypy

`app.py` contains just two lines of code:

```
$ cat app.py 
import logging

print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.values())
```

output:

```
dict_values([])
```

so it runs successfully, but mypy complains

```
$ mypy app.py 
app.py:3:7: error: "Type[Logger]" has no attribute "manager"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

wondering why?

Comment: I am hitting the same issue.  My IDE is PyCharm, and I use its built-in inspections.  When entering `logging.Logger.manager`, it also warns, saying `Unresolved attribute reference 'manager' for class 'Logger'`.  I think it has to do with the fact that `Logger` doesn't have an instance attribute `manager`, and the `manager` attribute is added at runtime via `Logger.manager = Manager(Logger.root)` (line 1732 in my `logging.__init__.py`)

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: `Module 'codecs' has no attribute 'escape_decode'` is the issue im tripping over. `codecs.escape_decode()` works fine but mypy doesnt seem to believe it.

Comment: I'd recommend creating an issue on https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues.

But note that the logging docs don't seem to mention anything about the manager, but It can see it in the code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fc3dca3e16a62690707dcdc923a577e5167a8e2a/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1922